# Как правильно употреблять глаголы "открывать" и "открыть"?

Tags: выбор-слов, глаголы

Проверьте следующее предложение!Правильно ли употребление глагола в скобочках?

*Когда на улице холодно, мы не (открыли) окно, но вчера вечером, несмотря на холод, весь день мы (открывали) его.*

Comment: "Несмотря" надо слитно.

Comment: Вторая часть предложения невозможна при любом глаголе. Пропущен предлог **на**, не иначе.

Comment: Спасибо! Но извините, пожалуйста! Я не очень поняла, куда надо поставить предлог 'на'. Вы можете написать полное предложение. И в первой части предложения невозможно с глаголом НСВ 'открываем'?